# Cannot convert 'wchar_t' to 'LPCSTR'

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode

I'm using Atom as my Editor and I have the g++ compiler to compile my C++ file.

The Code snippet in question is:

```
bool openComPort(wchar_t* portSpecifier)
{
    DCB dcb;

    // Open Serial Port
    wprintf(L"Opening COM PORT: %s",portSpecifier);
    printf("\n");

    serialPort = CreateFile(portSpecifier,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

    if (serialPort == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        wprintf(L"Error opening Serial port: %s\n",portSpecifier);
        return(false);
    }

    ...

    return true;
}
```

And if I want to Compile it, I always get the Error:

> error: cannot convert 'wchar_t' to 'LPCSTR' {aka 'const char'} serialPort = CreateFile(portSpecifier,GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE,0,NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,0,NULL);

I've read it should have something to do with Windows and UNICODE or ASCII.

I made sure Atom uses UNICODE by pressing ctrl+shift+U and selecting UTF-8.

I tried to `#define UNICODE` in the beginning. Didn't work.

I've tried different solutions from other threads like:

```
(_TCHAR*)wprintf(L"Opening COM PORT: %s",portSpecifier);
```

Still i always get the same error. Do you have any suggestion on how to fix this?

Comment: Looks like your build has unicode turned off. `CreateFileW` eats wide `char`s, but it might be better to find the option in your tools that turns unicode on.

Comment: I'd argue that `_T` and the like are a cludge to allow code to compile on legacy systems. Use `WCHAR` and `*W` function variants, i.e. `CreateFileW()` in this case. BTW: This really needs a [mcve]. That would have told you the answer to the initial question about opencv as well, i.e. that it's irrelevant.

Comment: @FelixKunz Did you remove some `*` from the error message? It doesn't make sense without them.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt Error's gone! Thanks man! This was the solution. I've added the W before, but not at the correct position. oh, and about the minimal reproducible example... i shrunk the code to the point where i knew what the error is, but i didn't know how much i can reduce it more, so you'll be still able to figure out the context. About the opencv thing im sorry, i should have figured out by myself, that opencv has nothing to do with it.

Comment: Alternatively, specify the preprocessor symbols on the g++ command line (e.g. `-DUNICODE -D_UNICODE`).

Comment: @FelixKunz the point is kind of moot, since the problem here is a piece of information that you didn't know, but reproducible is just as important as minimal. You've got minimal nailed here, but what you really want is a teeny-tiny program that would run if not for the one pesky compiler error. In most cases if you can get the program down to the point where it is complete and nothing but the one problem you're interested in solving the cause of the problem jumps right out because there is nothing left for it to hide behind. Do it right and you won't have to ask a question at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing CreateFile to CreateFileW.

Microsoft has two versions of all the older Win32 calls that involve strings, one for the multibyte character set and one for what it calls Unicode by which it means UTF-16 / UCS-2, basically two bytes per character Unicode. If the API call is CreateFoo, the two versions of the call will be CreateFooA and CreateFooW, then in the Windows headers somewhere CreateFoo will be defined as a macro that expands to either CreateFooA or CreateFooW depending on whether the UNICODE preprocessor definition is defined.

If you were working in Visual Studio the declaration of that preprocessor definition is controlled by a project setting in the GUI. Since you are not, try directly calling the Unicode version of CreateFile if you are working with wide characters.

Comment: "_two versions of all_" -- newer API tend to have only a single `wchar_t` interface without the `W` suffix.